# Applicant - Trial first or course? access database design

Tags: ms-access, registration

Im designing a database for a college registration system where the student can be put straight into a course or do a trial.

I have my application table
{applicant I.D (not student I.D as they have not been granted a course yet)
, First Name, 
Last Name, 
Address, 
Etc, }

Tutor Table
{Tutor ID, 
first Name, 
Last name, }

my Courses table
{Course Id, 
Course Name, 
tutor ID, }

my trial table
{Trial I.D, Day of trial, type of trial}

how can i sign one student up for either a course or a trial?
and once they have sat the trial, how offer/reject thema  course?

i have a registeration table but im not sure what to put in it

i have
{registeration Id, applicant id, course i.d, trial i,d)

is this correct?

Comment: Have you read something on the lines of [Relational database design](http://r937.com/relational.html)?

Comment: i know about basic relationships
its how to choose between the Trial and the Course i can't figure out

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what you mean by trial?